# Learning Ruby with Rubymonk I don't understand Run a block of code N times

Tags: ruby, control-flow

Rubymonk give you a block of code :

```
# add a loop inside this method to ring the bell 'n' times
def ring(bell, n)
  bell.ring
end
```

and for the solution gives you this:

```
def ring(bell, n)
  n.times do
    bell.ring
  end
end
```

I understand what the loop is doing but I don't get what the first parameter of the method does or how to invoke the method with the correct arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bell` is just an object with a `ring` method.

Example:

```
class MyBell
  def ring
    print "***ring***\n"
  end
end


def ring(bell, n)
  n.times do
    bell.ring
  end
end

b = MyBell.new()
ring(b, 4)
```